# VueJS: ReferenceError 'is not defined' when pass instance of v-for to style

Tags: vue.js

I h ave a trouble to implement class.
My `<a>` has two css classes - `normal', '`fault'.

Below is my html code.

```
<a href="#none" v-for="busstop in busstops"     
   id="busstop.id"
   :class="['marker', isBusStopFail(busstop) ? 'fault': 'normal']"                        
   onclick="detailsOpen(this);"></a>
```

And, below is my vuejs code.

```
data: {
   busstops: []
   ....
methods: {
   isBusStopFail: function(busstop) {
      let failDevice = bussstop.fail;
      if (failDevice.led || failDevice.usb || failDevice.bell || failDevice.gw) {
             return false;
      } else {
             return true;
      }
  },
  ...
```

My goal is pass instance to method.
But vuejs said

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: bussstop is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a typing error. Check the line with

```
let failDevice = bussstop.fail;
```

and change to

```
let failDevice = busstop.fail;
```